# How to decode/decrypt/decipher an unknown 83 bytes long UDP payload?

Tags: encryption, decryption

I have an unknown 83 bytes long payload which I would like to decode/decrypt/decipher…

I got an alarm system from vendor [www.jablotron.com](http://www.jablotron.com), an old device, but it works perfectly.

It’s JA-63 with a LAN extension card JA-60WEB. JA-60WEB is via Ethernet supposed to send all events detected by the alarm system to a CMS (Central Monitoring System).

JA-60WEB Installation manual: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1199886/Jablotron-Ja-60web.html#manual

According to the manual the device should send event messages via IP CID protocol which I assume stand for Contact ID over IP protocol.

Contact ID protocol described here:
https://li0r.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/sia-dc-05-1999-09_contact_id.pdf

It should be a simple ASCII string, 16 byte long messages, in format (for example) like this: 1234 18 1131 01 015 8.
But unfortunately, it’s not.

I sniffed the traffic (Wireshark) outgoing from JA-60WEB to my fictive CMS receiver and got the following pattern.

I configured JA-60WEB module to send only messages when the following event happened: “Exit programming mode”. To have a static event message always.

I repeated the event 6 times, therefore below 54 times HEX stream of the UDP payload (each time 83 bytes long).

I observed that JA-60WEB sends each event 9 times. First time the real message, and after that it retries to send 8 times again as it did not receive the acknowledgment from CMS, that the message was received correctly. I have no real CMS, I’m trying to develop my own CMS, therefore the whole effort here.

My question: What is this? Binary encoded protocol? Encrypted somehow?

What is interesting is it’s for the same event slightly different stream and it should be static.
How would one approach this problem to detect what it is?

I also observed some patterns depicted here of another data sample. Like with every new message data is shifting to the left, and overwritten with something new incoming from the right side:
[image]

Data:

```
f090bb0c1c7023ece5b676ce4315a69c535a09770b91070742f9bdef381522a0502efc10e976858ed1e46ba14d5fa57140e38c726e9f7c0ac2f4520a9f7c9bddb6469da35efd13b38e859af4076e66fcdfca76
f091bb151c4323ece5b676ce5a15a69c535a09770b91070742cebdef381522a0502efc10e976a48ed1e46ba14d5fa57140e38c516e9f7c0ac2f4520a9f7c9bdd9f469da35efd13b38e859af4073166fcdfca50
f09e9a151c5223ece5b676ef5a15a69c535a09770b91070761cebdef381522a0502efc10e95fa48ed1e46ba14d5fa57140e3f3516e9f7c0ac2f4520a9f7c9b4c9f469da35efd13b38e859af4343166fcdfca22
f0769a151cab23ece5b69fef5a15a69c535a09770b91075861cebdef381522a0502efc10985fa48ed1e46ba14d5fa5714070f3516e9f7c0ac2f4520a9f7cd24c9f469da35efd13b38e859ac3343166fcdfca57
f0759a151cba23ece5b69fef5a15a69c535a09770b91f45861cebdef381522a0502efc99985fa48ed1e46ba14d5fa5715770f3516e9f7c0ac2f4520a9fbdd24c9f469da35efd13b38e8559c3343166fcdfca51
f0749a151c8d23ece5b69fef5a15a69c535a09770be6f45861cebdef381522a0502e7d99985fa48ed1e46ba14d5fa5725770f3516e9f7c0ac2f4520a26bdd24c9f469da35efd13b38eaa59c3343166fcdfca6e
f0739a151ce223ece5b69fef5a15a69c535a0977c8e6f45861cebdef381522a050f77d99985fa48ed1e46ba14d5f8a725770f3516e9f7c0ac2f4521b26bdd24c9f469da35efd13b3ddaa59c3343166fcdfca48
f0729a151cf523ece5b69fef5a15a69c535a0998c8e6f45861cebdef381522a021f77d99985fa48ed1e46ba14dec8a725770f3516e9f7c0ac2f46b1b26bdd24c9f469da35efd13a4ddaa59c3343166fcdfca1c
f0719a151cc423ece5659fef5a15a69c535ada98c8e6f45861cebdef381522b921f77d99985fa48ed1e46ba17aec8a725770f3516e9f7c0ac2d56b1b26bdd24c9f469da35efd30a4ddaa59c3343166fcdfca71
f0709a151c0223ec72659fef5a15a69c53cdda98c8e6f45861cebdef381503b921f77d99985fa48ed1e46b827aec8a725770f3516e9f7c0aebd56b1b26bdd24c9f469da35e0230a4ddaa59c3343166fcdfca93
f06f9a151c15230f72659fef5a15a69cb0cdda98c8e6f45861cebdef387c03b921f77d99985fa48ed1e4b4827aec8a725770f3516e9f7cfbebd56b1b26bdd24c9f469da3cd0230a4ddaa59c3343166fcdf03b6
f06e9a151c649c0f72659fef5a15a623b0cdda98c8e6f45861cebdef297c03b921f77d99985fa48ed197b4827aec8a725770f3516e9ff5fbebd56b1b26bdd24c9f469db4cd0230a4ddaa59c3343166fc9e03b8
f06d9a151c6e9c0f72659fef5a15b523b0cdda98c8e6f45861cebda6297c03b921f77d99985fa48e2697b4827aec8a725770f3516e1ef5fbebd56b1b26bdd24c9f469eb4cd0230a4ddaa59c3343166459e038c
f06c9a158b5f9c0f72659fef5a82b523b0cdda98c8e6f45861ce7ca6297c03b921f77d99985fa4cd2697b4827aec8a725770f351371ef5fbebd56b1b26bdd24c9f699eb4cd0230a4ddaa59c3343177459e03f7
f06b9a968b4c9c0f72659fefd982b523b0cdda98c8e6f45861377ca6297c03b921f77d99985fcbcd2697b4827aec8a725770f3a0371ef5fbebd56b1b26bdd24c2c699eb4cd0230a4ddaa59c3340877459e0380
f06af5968ba79c0f72659f80d982b523b0cdda98c8e6f458f0377ca6297c03b921f77d99980ccbcd2697b4827aec8a725770eaa0371ef5fbebd56b1b26bdd27b2c699eb4cd0230a4ddaa59c3150877459e03cc
f01af5968b949c0f7265ec80d982b523b0cdda98c8e6f4a1f0377ca6297c03b921f77d990f0ccbcd2697b4827aec8a725751eaa0371ef5fbebd56b1b26bdf17b2c699eb4cd0230a4ddaa59ea150877459e03fc
f01bf5968b859c0f7265ec80d982b523b0cdda98c8e615a1f0377ca6297c03b921f77dfa0f0ccbcd2697b4827aec8a72be51eaa0371ef5fbebd56b1b26e2f17b2c699eb4cd0230a4ddaa28ea150877459e03ec
f014f5968b369c0f7265ec80d982b523b0cdda98c88f15a1f0377ca6297c03b921f7c2fa0f0ccbcd2697b4827aec8a63be51eaa0371ef5fbebd56b1bd5e2f17b2c699eb4cd0230a4dd2328ea150877459e03e1
f015f5968b279c0f7265ec80d982b523b0cdda98f98f15a1f0377ca6297c03b921e4c2fa0f0ccbcd2697b4827aec4363be51eaa0371ef5fbebd56b6cd5e2f17b2c699eb4cd0230a45c2328ea150877459e03f1
f016f5968b149c0f7265ec80d982b523b0cdda91f98f15a1f0377ca6297c03b9b6e4c2fa0f0ccbcd2697b4827aad4363be51eaa0371ef5fbebd5a86cd5e2f17b2c699eb4cd02307d5c2328ea150877459e03c1
f017f5968b0f9c0f7264ec80d982b523b0cddb91f98f15a1f0377ca6297c033ab6e4c2fa0f0ccbcd2697b48203ad4363be51eaa0371ef5fbeb3aa86cd5e2f17b2c699eb4cd02417d5c2328ea150877459e03be
f010f5968b7c9c0fab64ec80d982b523b014db91f98f15a1f0377ca6297cec3ab6e4c2fa0f0ccbcd2697b41303ad4363be51eaa0371ef5fb383aa86cd5e2f17b2c699eb4cd1b417d5c2328ea150877459e03e0
f011f5968b6d9c3eab64ec80d982b5238114db91f98f15a1f0377ca6298fec3ab6e4c2fa0f0ccbcd2697cd1303ad4363be51eaa0371ef56c383aa86cd5e2f17b2c699eb4ec1b417d5c2328ea150877459e20f0
f012f5968b44053eab64ec80d982b5ba8114db91f98f15a1f0377ca6de8fec3ab6e4c2fa0f0ccbcd26f6cd1303ad4363be51eaa0371e166c383aa86cd5e2f17b2c699eddec1b417d5c2328ea150877454120cb
f013f5968b54053eab64ec80d98254ba8114db91f98f15a1f0377c45de8fec3ab6e4c2fa0f0ccbcdcff6cd1303ad4363be51eaa037a1166c383aa86cd5e2f17b2c698fddec1b417d5c2328ea1508773641208c
f0b15bc3fe5721d5040fb12d8cf7589e6abbb0a642900e571229fe100ba5323060becca0e80fd45e21b404928afc1a82e7819af0076e85fcc8cab8fce552d0523df0dfed93a8a67e73b02f0843ca39e7681655
f0b05bc3fe3821d5040fb12d8cf7589e6abbb0a64290d7571229fe100ba5323060becc69e80fd45e21b404928afc1a828e819af0076e85fcc8cab8fce5cbd0523df0dfed93a8a67e73b0960843ca39e7681649
f0b35bc3fe3792d5040fb12d8cf7582d6abbb0a64290d7571229fe1048a5323060becc69e80fd45e21a704928afc1a828e819af0076e66fcc8cab8fce5cbd0523df0df3e93a8a67e73b0960843ca39e76b165d
f0b25bc3fe2692d5040fb12d8cf7582d6abbb0a642e1d7571229fe1048a5323060be8d69e80fd45e21a704928afc1ab38e819af0076e66fcc8cab8fc84cbd0523df0df3e93a8a67e73a1960843ca39e76b164d
f0b55bc3fef892d5040fb12d8cf76f2d6abbb0a642e1d7571229fe7f48a5323060be8d69e80fd45eb6a704928afc1ab38e819af0073166fcc8cab8fc84cbd0523df0c83e93a8a67e73a1960843ca39c86b1666
f0b45bc3fec992d5040fb12d8cf76f2d6abbb0a65be1d7571229fe7f48a5323060c78d69e80fd45eb6a704928afc13b38e819af0073166fcc8cab8d584cbd0523df0c83e93a8a67e4aa1960843ca39c86b161d
f0b75bc3ddda92d5040fb12d8cd46f2d6abbb0a65be1d7571229ad7f48a5323060c78d69e80fd4ddb6a704928afc13b38e819af0343166fcc8cab8d584cbd0523dd3c83e93a8a67e4aa1960843ca8ac86b1646
f0b65bc3dda192d5040fb12d8cd46f2d6abbb0875be1d7571229ad7f48a53230f1c78d69e80fd4ddb6a704928afd13b38e819af0343166fcc8ca29d584cbd0523dd3c83e93a8a65f4aa1960843ca8ac86b1627
f0b95b9cddb292d5040fb12dd3d46f2d6abbb0875be1d75712bead7f48a53230f1c78d69e80fbbddb6a704928afd13b38e819ac7343166fcc8ca29d584cbd05242d3c83e93a8a65f4aa1960843fd8ac86b1608
f0b85b9cdd8392d50466b12dd3d46f2d6abbd9875be1d75712bead7f48a53249f1c78d69e80fbbddb6a7049253fd13b38e819ac7343166fcc80329d584cbd05242d3c83e93a88f5f4aa1960843fd8ac86b1673
f0bba89cdd4992d50466b1ded3d46f2d6abbd9875be1d75771bead7f48a53249f1c78d69e87cbbddb6a7049253fd13b38e8159c7343166fcc80329d584cbd0c142d3c83e93a88f5f4aa1960860fd8ac86b163d
f0baa89cdd5a92d51566b1ded3d46f2d6aaad9875be1d75771bead7f48a55349f1c78d69e87cbbddb6a704a353fd13b38e8159c7343166fc890329d584cbd0c142d3c83e93598f5f4aa1960860fd8ac86b1651
f0caa89cdd2b92d51566c6ded3d46f2d6aaad9875be1d7e871bead7f48a55349f1c78d699f7cbbddb6a704a353fd13b38eae59c7343166fc890329d584cbc7c142d3c83e93598f5f4aa1965760fd8ac86b1665
f0cba89cdd32929c1566c6ded3d46f2d23aad9875be1d7e871bead7f484c5349f1c78d699f7cbbddb6a79da353fd13b38eae59c734316645890329d584cbc7c142d3c83e1a598f5f4aa1965760fd8ac86b7f47
f0c8a89cdd03929c1566c6ded3d46f2d23aad9875be1c4e871bead7f484c5349f1c78d0a9f7cbbddb6a79da353fd13b3ddae59c734316645890329d584c8c7c142d3c83e1a598f5f4aa1655760fd8ac86b7f2a
f0c9a89cdd14539c1566c6ded3d46fec23aad9875be1c4e871bead7f794c5349f1c78d0a9f7cbbddb6469da353fd13b3ddae59c734317745890329d584c8c7c142d3c8bf1a598f5f4aa1655760fd8ac87a7f7e
f0d6a89cddfb539c1566c6ded3d46fec23aad9875b76c4e871bead7f794c5349f1c7520a9f7cbbddb6469da353fd13a4ddae59c734317745890329d5abc8c7c142d3c8bf1a598f5f4ad6655760fd8ac87a7f5a
f0d7a89cdd35539c1566c6ded3d496ec23aad9875b76c4e871bead76794c5349f1c7520a9f7cbbdd9f469da353fd13a4ddae59c734087745890329d5abc8c7c142d391bf1a598f5f4ad6655760fd8a817a7f65
f0d4a89cdd24539c1566c6ded3d496ec23aad987d876c4e871bead76794c5349f1f4520a9f7cbbdd9f469da353fd30a4ddae59c73408774589032966abc8c7c142d391bf1a598f5f89d6655760fd8a817a7f63
f0d5a89c4cb3539c1566c6ded34596ec23aad987d876c4e871beac76794c5349f1f4520a9f7cbb4c9f469da353fd30a4ddae59c71508774589032966abc8c7c1422291bf1a598f5f89d6655760fd4b817a7f7e
f0d2a89c4ca2539c1566c6ded34596ec23aad968d876c4e871beac76794c5349c6f4520a9f7cbb4c9f469da3530230a4ddae59c71508774589031e66abc8c7c1422291bf1a598fb089d6655760fd4b817a7f54
f0d3a8654cd5539c1566c6de2a4596ec23aad968d876c4e871e7ac76794c5349c6f4520a9f7cf24c9f469da3530230a4ddae59ee1508774589031e66abc8c7c15b2291bf1a598fb089d6655760044b817a7f1e
f0d0a8654cca539c1595c6de2a4596ec23aa2a68d876c4e871e7ac76794c530ac6f4520a9f7cf24c9f469da3c00230a4ddae59ee1508774589201e66abc8c7c15b2291bf1a595cb089d6655760044b817a7f6e
f0d149654cfd539c1595c63f2a4596ec23aa2a68d876c4e840e7ac76794c530ac6f4520a9fbdf24c9f469da3c00230a4ddae28ee1508774589201e66abc8c7e05b2291bf1a595cb089d66557f1044b817a7f51
f0de49654cec539ce295c63f2a4596ec235d2a68d876c4e840e7ac76794c7c0ac6f4520a9fbdf24c9f469db4c00230a4ddae28ee1508774556201e66abc8c7e05b2291bf1ace5cb089d66557f1044b817a7fcc
f0b649654c05539ce295af3f2a4596ec235d2a68d876c47140e7ac76794c7c0ac6f4520a26bdf24c9f469db4c00230a4dd2728ee1508774556201e66abc82ee05b2291bf1ace5cb089d665aef1044b817a7fdd
f0b549654c34537fe295af3f2a4596ecc05d2a68d876c47140e7ac76799f7c0ac6f4520a26bdf24c9f469eb4c00230a4dd2728ee1508773656201e66abc82ee05b2291bff9ce5cb089d665aef1044b817a8cb0
f0b449654c27537fe295af3f2a4596ecc05d2a68d876a57140e7ac76799f7c0ac6f4521b26bdf24c9f469eb4c00230a45c2728ee1508773656201e66abd92ee05b2291bff9ce5cb089d684aef1044b817a8cfd
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: When decoding an unknown protocol, don't forget to generate some interesting protocol messages. This is "exit programming mode"; did you also try arming the alarm, disarming, setting it off, tampering? And are you absolutely sure that CID = Contact ID?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is only about reverse engineering - I don't see any security aspect here. It would be more on-topic at [reverseengineering.se].